# Reusing Electron session

Tags: session, electron

Say I have a `BrowserWindow` set up with the following options:

```
{
  webPreferences:{
    partition: 'persist:example'
  }
}
```

I am also making a call to `app.setPath` to set `userData` to a local directory.

If I open my Electron application and log in, close the application, then open a new instance, I am still logged in.  This is expected session behavior.

However, if I open my Electron application and log in, then open a second instance of my application with the same `BrowserWindow` settings and same application paths, the second instance will not be logged in, despite being propped up to use the same user data and partition.

Shouldn't the second instance be able to use session information from the first instance without closing the first instance?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, but I haven't taken a deeper look into it for some time.  This was also several versions of `electron-prebuilt`, it's entirely possible it's been fixed.